# Can we create multiple instance of hyperledger composer rest server for same business network?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

To understand application architecture of composer rest server, I would like to understand following things.

Lets say, We have 4 peers of different organization. Now, What would be recommended approach in context of how we would be managing composer rest server.

1) Having one composer rest server per peer

2) Having one composer rest server per network and all peers will share composer rest server

3) Having one composer rest server per channel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly, just to confirm its called 'Hyperledger Composer' and 'Fabric Composer' was its old name from way back.

secondly, the answer is you would have one or more (think HA and availability) REST server instances per Composer business network, per Organisation that participates in that business network. It is also dependent on how each deploys REST server instances within their own infrastructure zones and somewhat dependent what user / user base will be authenticating to it  (the likelihood is they would be authenticating their own users / REST clients to consume the REST server APIs - by whatever the chosen Passport strategy is, to authenticate in a multi-user environment - eg. LDAP OAuth2 etc. So, the REST server is not strictly tied to 'peers' per se. The peer information is defined in the connection profile info, in the business network card.

Composer business networks are deployed to a specific channel/ledger -  and configured so in the business network cards that access it - the connection info specifies the channel, and the REST server instance is instantiated using an appropriate business network card.

See more on deploying your REST server here:
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/deploying-the-rest-server.html

Comment: Thank you Paul, Corrected composer name in question, sorry for the same

In summary, We will have one composer instance per channel and number of composer instances is depend on each organization's HA architecture, whether they would like to have only one instance of rest server or multiple. 

As multiple channel configuration is not possible in single business network card, We will have at least one instance of composer rest server per channel. If one peer is participating into two different channel, then it would required to connect two different composer rest server. Please correct me?

Comment: yes, that would be the case - because the connection info is different (the channel) - thus in that example, also requires two business network cards for those REST server instances. All other things being equal etc.